# what's the meaning of fault proneness of the used api

Tags: android

I'm a beginner  so i need a simple explanation for : 
1) what's an API in android library 
2) change of used android api 
3) fault proneness  of used android api 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An API is how you talk with the library, server or whatever that you are trying to communicate with. If it's a library, their API is the functionality that they provide publicly for you (and other users) to use.

Fault-Proneness (or Error prone) means that an API is designed in a way that the users of the API can get fault/errors If they are not careful about using it. On the other side, an API can be "safe" If their users cannot make unexpected errors or failures with them.

Answer (score 0):

API in general stands for "Application programming interface" and it is a set of clearly defined methods of communication among various components.

The **API for an Android library are just the methods you call in order to use that library**.

But the term API usually stands for "Remote API" such as a REST API with whom you communicate via HTTP or other protocols. Such as a webserver.

Comment: thank u so much . plz do u have any idea about the meaning of fault proneness of the used api

Comment: It just means that the API is likely to fail or make errors. So the API is "capable of making an error". Please accept my answer, if i could answer your question.